# What numbers do they mean?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

There are four nations using different types of numbers in mathematics.
There are:

**Nation x: A, B, C, D**

**Nation y: 1, 2, 3, 4**

**Nation z: i, ii, iii, iv**

**Nation t: a, b, c, d**

They may not be the same values when converting their numbers to another nation, e.g.: 1 may not equal to A or i or a.

You are given some clues:

1. The value of **A** in nation **y** is either **3** or **4** and in nation **z** is neither **iii** nor **iv**
2. The difference of **D** minus **C** in nation **y** is larger than **1** in our understanding
3. The value of **B** in nation **z** is not **iv**
4. The value of **2** is equal to **d** but not equal to **ii**
5. The value of **i** in nation **t** is **c** or **d**
6. The alphabet that comes before the value of **B** in nation **t** is equal to **iv** in nation **z** and **4** in nation **y**

Comment: Hi QingHong, when you say "**We** are given some clues" this sounds like you found the puzzle elsewhere - if so, could you please include an attribution as to where you came across it, so that the original content creator gets credit? Thanks :)

Comment: Ah okay, no worries - thanks for confirming :) Just wanted to check!

Comment: The numbers mason, what do they mean? :)

Comment: I want to clarify for clue 2, is the number 1 referenced in the question our understanding of 1 (like, real world) or nation y's understanding where it could mean a different value?

Comment: Could we please convert nation y to the "opqr" number system? Having actual numbers floating around the puzzle only makes it harder to read, since you always have to check if it's nation y's system or ours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is

> A = 3 = ii = a
>  B = 2 = i = d
>  C = 1 = iii = b
>  D = 4 = iv = c

with the solution graph

> [image: solution]

Comment: Any chance you could provide some selected logic steps, please? After applying all the base clues I ended up hitting a dead end with only clue 6 logic left in play and I still can't see where I went wrong - would be interested to find out...! Thanks :)

Comment: @Stiv I can do so, but to be honest rot13(V tbg fghpx univat gb thrff N gb n naq P gb o (naq fb ba) nf V pbhyqa'g svther bhg sebz gur pyhrf. NSNVX gubfr frgf pna or fjvgpurq onfrq ba gur pyhrf tvira.)

Comment: Ah, that's what I feared, as I couldn't find a way to make the solution unique either... [This was as far as I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRbdZ.png), then I couldn't spot the next step. I'd be keen to know if anyone can point out my error!

Comment: @Stiv rot13(Onfrq ba gur ynfg pyhr, jr xabj gurer vf n inyhr gung pbzrf orsber O, fb O pnaabg or gur ybjrfg inyhr. Gung zrnaf gung P vf (onfrq ba gur bgure vasbezngvba lbh unir va lbhe tencu) vf gur ybjrfg naq O vf gur frpbaq ybjrfg. Gung fubhyq trg lbh n ovg shegure.)

Comment: Hmmm... I thought I'd dealt with that already, since the lowest value in 't' is 'a', which I therefore ruled out. I think there must be an easier way to present this puzzle without causing so much confusion about values in all these different number systems...

Comment: @Stiv I fully agree